# How to call and view an array in a function

Tags: php, arrays, function, loops, foreach

I'm new to PHP and Kohana.
I would like to know how to call an array in a function.

I'm having the variable $productlist and I would like to add more elements into it with a function.

```
public $productlist =  array();
public function action_index()
{
   $product = new Product("Laptop","HP4897");
   $product2 = new Product("TV","Samsung 8773");


   $productlist[] = product;
   $productlist[] = product2;

   $this->add_product_to_array("Ebook","Everything you want to know");
   $this->show_productlist();
}

public function add_product_to_array($product_name, $product_description)
{
    $newproduct = new Product($product_name, $product_description);
    array_push($productlist,$newproduct);
}
public function show_productlist(){
    foreach($productlist as $key => $value)
    {
        print_r($value->get_product_name().'</br>');
    }
}
```

and this is the exception i'm getting:
*ErrorException [ Warning ]: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given*

if I'm adding foreach($this->productlist as $key => $value), it tells me it can't find productlist.

Product.php

```
class Product {

private $_product_name;
private $_product_description;


function __construct($name,$description)
{
    $this->_product_name = $name;
    $this->_product_description = $description;
}

public function get_product_name()
{
    return  $this->_product_name;
}
//etc
```

Comment: Are these functions (add_product_to_array, etc.) part of a class? If so, then you can refer to the list of products as $this->productlist within any of the functions. If not, then you ought to consider making a class of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PHP Classes and Objects - The Basics](http://php.net/oop5.basic)

Inside the class when you access the `$productlist` array you need to use `$this->productlist`.  You seem to have known this in the `Product` class.  What happened?

Comment: I failed with a $ somewhere in my code which didn't belong there. Thanks for pointing out the $this->productlist.. I had $this->$productlist.